# addToBackStack() with Fragment's instantiate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have implemented a Sherlock `ActionBar`  with navigation tabs using a tabs adapter. Below is my tab adapter class:

```
 public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo
    {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
        {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager)
    {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
    {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext,info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels)
    {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position)
    {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
    {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++)
        {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)
            {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is how to use **addToBackStack()** with `Fragment.instantiate()`(or if there is any other way for handling back button)?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is how to use addtobackstack with Fragment.instantiate or
>   any other way for handling back button

You really shouldn't do this. If you're going to use tabs with fragments in a `ViewPager` it's safe to assume the user could switch/swipe a lot the tab fragments as he uses the app. Having the BACK button recreating his steps when he wants out of the activity could be very frustrating(imagine trying to get out of this activity after switching tabs for 15-20 times).

If you really want to do that then store the user's navigation path in a list/array of integers(when swiping/switching the tabs store the int position of the `ViewPager`'s page where the user has gone). Then override the `onBackPressed` method of the activity and have it pop(every time the BACK button is clicked) the last position from the previous list/array moving the `ViewPager` to that position(along with highlighting the proper tab).